# Integrating Bootstrap carousel in WordPress without plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have integarted bootstrap carousel into my wordpress. The slides will be taken from the posts which will be tagged as "featured" so only 5 recently enter "featured" posts will be shown.

Below is my code:

```
<div id="carousel-captions" class="carousel slide bs-docs-carousel hidden-xs">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-captions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-captions" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-captions" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-captions" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-captions" data-slide-to="4" class=""></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'tag=featured&orderby=date&posts_per_page=5' ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="item">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <img src="<?php the_field('header_banner', $post_id); ?>" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3><?php the_field('year', $post_id); ?></h3><span class="name">Make<br><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></span><hr>
              <p><?php the_field('mileage', $post_id); ?> Miles | <?php the_field('exterior_color', $post_id); ?> Color<br><br><?php echo homepage_carousel_excerpt(15); ?></p><span class="btn btn-default">Details&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&rarr;</span>
            </div></a>
          </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else:  ?>
  <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>


        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-captions" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-captions" data-slide="next">
          <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
</div>
```

The problem is It doesn't slide because the "active" class is not working statically.

HOw do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To avoid having to query twice, you can set a variable set to 1 outside your loop. In the loop, you add the "active" class when it's equal to 1, then you increment it.

```
<?php
// Previous code here...
$i = 1;
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
         ?>
        <div class="item<?php if ($i == 1) echo 'active'; ?>">

        </div>
<?php
    $i++;
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Hey @feub----the Carousel indicators stop at 10---any idea where to find the code to change this (bootstrap.js I would think.  I created a post a few weeks ago trying to resolve this and got a Tumbleweed badge for no answers.

Comment: hi @feub you should have space before active like this ' active' or the result will be `itemactive` not `item active` so the code should be `<div class="item<?php if ($i == 1) echo ' active'; ?>">` with space before the word active

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
<?php
 $args = array(
 'post_type'      => 'slides',
 'oderby'         => 'menu_order',
 'posts_per_page' => -1
 );

$slides = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $slides->have_posts() ): ?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
      <!--Twitter bootstrap Photo carrousel-->
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide center-block"     data-ride="carousel" >
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php while( $slides->have_posts() ) : $slides->the_post(); $index++ ?>

      <?php if ( $index == 1 ): ?>
        <div class="item active">
      <?php else: ?>
        <div class="item">
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div><!-- carrousel ends here -->
```

I learnt this by watching the following video: [Integrating the Bootstrap Carousel into the WordPress theme](https://www.youtube.com/)  by user Ezer Sanbe. All credits to him.

**The youtube video or the channel for this user are no longer available, sorry**

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah you are right. Sorry, it seems that the video nor the channel are available anymore

Answer (score 0):

Limit the first query to 1 post. In that first loop, set the carousel item class to active. Reset the query and run a second loop, offset by one, and negate the active class, like so:

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php
          $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
           'post_type' =>'post',
           'posts_per_page' => 1
         ));
         while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
         $the_query->the_post();
         ?>
        <div class="item active">
            First Slide
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php
         $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
          'post_type' =>'post',
          'offset' => 1
         ));
         while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
         $the_query->the_post();
         ?>
         <div class="item">
            Remaining Slides
         </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 with custom post type (here named "diapositives"):

```
<!-- Define the loop -->
        <?php $diapositivesloop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'diapositives', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
        <?php $i=1; ?>
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <?php while ( $diapositivesloop->have_posts() ) : $diapositivesloop->the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>


                <div class="item <?php if ($i == 1) echo 'active'; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                    </div>
                </div>



        <!-- End of the loop -->
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php 
            $slider = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'slider',
                'posts_per_page'    => 7,
            ));
        ?>

        <?php 
        if ( have_posts() ) {
            $x=0;
            while ( $slider->have_posts() ) {
                $x++;
                $slider->the_post(); ?>

                <!-- Begin Slide 1 -->

                <div class="item <?php if($x==1){ echo 'active'; }?>">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('slider-img'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3 class="carousel-title hidden-xs"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <p class="carousel-body"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- End Slide 1 -->

            <?php } // end while
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } // end if
        ?>


    </div>

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators visible-lg">
        <?php 
            for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++){ ?>
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="<?php if( $i==0 ){echo 'active'; }?>"></li>
            <?php }
        ?>
    </ol>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Integrating Bootstrap carousel in WordPress without plugin

```
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php $slider = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'slider',
        'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    )); ?>
    <?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        $x=0;
        while ( $slider->have_posts() ) {
            $x++;
            $slider->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="<?php if($x==1){echo 'active'} ?> item">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
        <?php } // end while
    } // end if
    ?>


    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->

     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++; ) { ?>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;  ?>" class="<?php if($i==0){ echo 'active' }?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ol>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```