# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Dynamicly For Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html

Here is my issue ! i'm trying to code a wordpress slider with the html bootstrap 4 default carousel and i find some hard time because i'm noobie in php !
i'm here to find if someone could give me an example for getting bootstrap 4 carousel images from wordpress category

here an exemple with getting images from tags :

```
         <?php $args = array(

            'posts_per_page' => 5,

            'tag' => 'slider'

         );

         $slider = new WP_Query($args);

         if($slider->have_posts()):

         $count = $slider->found_posts;

         ?>

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">

               <?php for($i = 0; $i < $count ;  $i++) { ?>

                      <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="<?php echo ($i == 0) ? 'active' : ''?>"></li>

                <?php } ?>

            </ol> <!--.carousel-indicators-->



            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

               <?php $i = 0; while($slider->have_posts()): $slider->the_post(); ?>

                   <div class="carousel-item <?php echo ($i == 0) ? 'active' : ''?>">

                         <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'slider', array(

                                                                 'class' => 'd-block img-fluid',

                                                                 'alt' => get_the_title() ) ) ; ?>

                         <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">

                             <h3 class="text-uppercase"><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></h3>

                         </div>

                   </div><!--.carousel-item-->

                <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

            </div> <!--.carouse-inner-->





            <a href="#main-slider" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">

                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>

            </a>

            <a href="#main-slider" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">

                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>

            </a>



         <?php endif;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like this
https://hartdesign.co.nz/portfolio-item/blackmagic-2/
look in the bottom of the page the gallery?

Comment: Yes please ! i just want it to be with bootstrap 4 carousel and dynamicly get images from wordpress categoris

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344696/integrating-bootstrap-carousel-in-wordpress-without-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, just remove the `'tag' => 'slider'` or add posts with the tag "slider".